# Vue.js context and Promise scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, this, es6-promise

Fairly new to Vue.js here and I've been wrestling with this for a bit and getting nowhere, so I figured I'd ask.

I'm having trouble accessing the Vue context within a Promise (in a method) in an app I'm trying to build. I tried to [replicate it via JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7yforqh/1/) and failed, so I'm going to add screenshots of DevTools and hopefully someone can make sense of it/explain what's going on.

I can call into a method (via button click) and have access to the Vue context via `this`:
[image: this: VueComponent]

but the second I step into a Promise callback (using ES6's `() => {}`, which *should* maintain scope), `this` becomes `undefined`:
[image: this: undefined]

The only difference I can see between my app and the JSFiddle is that in mine, it's referencing the `VueContext` whereas on JSFiddle it's referencing `Vue`. This seems to be based on how it's declared/where the code lives (in a module vs. within the `new Vue()` declaration).

Again, new to Vue and haven't been able to find anything like this/figure it out myself. Happy to field any questions. Thanks!

Comment: try to console.log(this)，is the same result?

Comment: Yep :( For whatever reason this gets completely nuked within the Promise callback, which makes it pretty much impossible to interact with anything else in the applcation